# How to call a function after linkWithPopup function

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to call a function when `linkWithPopup` resolves with the following code:

```
_linkToCurrentUser: function(authId, provider) {
  this.user.linkWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    console.log("user linked ", result);
    this.updateUserInfos(authId); // <-- error: this.updateUserInfos is not a function
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
},
updateUserInfos: function(authId) {
  ...
}
```

But it results in this error:

> ```
>  Uncaught TypeError: this.updateUserInfos is not a function
> ```

However, the function works when it's outside of the `linkWithPopup` function:

```
_linkToCurrentUser: function(authId, provider) {
  this.user.linkWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    console.log("user linked ", result);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log( error);
  });

  this.updateUserInfos(authId); // <-- works
},
updateUserInfos: function(authId) {
  ...
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is the context of your callback is not bound to the Polymer object, so it uses the outer context (normally the `Window` object) for `this`.

You could switch to [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (assuming ES6 is available for you) to automatically bind the Polymer object:

```
_linkToCurentUser: function(authId, provider) {
  this.user.linkWithPopup(provider).then(result => { // <-- bind `this` to Polymer object
    console.log('user linked', result);
    this.updateUserInfos(authId);
  })
  ...
}
```

Or you could use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the context to the Polymer object:

```
_linkToCurentUser: function(authId, provider) {
  this.user.linkWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    console.log('user linked', result);
    this.updateUserInfos(authId);
  }.bind(this))  // <-- bind `this` to Polymer object
  ...
}
```

Or you could pass in a reference:

```
_linkToCurentUser: function(authId, provider) {
  var self = this; // <-- cache reference for use in callback
  this.user.linkWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    console.log('user linked', result);
    self.updateUserInfos(authId);
  })
  ...
}
```